# RandomAccessFileChannel write and then read, by cache or by disk IO

Tags: java, linux, nio

If I map a RandomAccessFileChannel to a ByteBuffer, write some bytes to it, and then read the previously written bytes from it, will the bytes read from buffer or from disk? Is the result affected by kernel version, read/write position or system-wide IO activity? Finally, how can I know if the bytes are read by RAM IO or disk IO? Thanks in advance.

```
fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(this.file, "rw").getChannel();
mappedByteBuffer = this.fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, fileSize);
```

Comment: Perhaps the documentation of [`FileChannel#map(MapMode,long,long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,long,long)) and [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) can answer at least some of your questions.

Comment: There is no buffering in `RandomAccessFile` at the Java level, but there almost certainly is at the operating system level, the disk driver level, and the disk controller level.